# Drawing over RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm trying to draw borders around words and paragraphs in RichTextBox but when I turn on UserPaint it doesn't draw text anymore while my custom painting seems to work. May be I just forgot to turn on something else? Here is what I have

```
public partial class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
{
    public RichTextBoxEx()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        //Do some painting here
    }
}
```

Using info from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041348/richtextbox-and-userpaint) didn't help me

Comment: Because I still get no text drawing after adding code from that example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked ok for me:

```
class RichBox : RichTextBox {
  private const int WM_PAINT = 15;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT) {
      this.Invalidate();
      base.WndProc(ref m);
      using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle)) {
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, Point.Empty, 
                   new Point(this.ClientSize.Width - 1,
                             this.ClientSize.Height - 1));
      }
    } else {
      base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Demarsch Comment out the `Invalidate()` line and then place enough text in the box to start scrolling and see what happens.

Comment: Well yes, I see why do I need it but I discovered another issue. When I hit enter it looks like new line is created but caret remains on the same line and if you enter any other text it appears on first line. If I comment out using... I get everything back. Any ideas?

Comment: @Demarsch I can't repro that.  My caret moves to the next line.

Comment: @LarcTech nevermind, this was my mistake I manually moved selection to identify the font which is used by particular character. Thanks again

Comment: All solutions, including this one and the one I linked to, end up drawing on top of the text. Is there any way you have found to draw behind the text? i.e. draw only the background?

Answer (score 2):

The events in rich textbox are a pain in the back since they don't fire the way you think they should fire. [Here's a post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/b3521ad3-7ceb-4019-b3ba-441aae1f5a41) where someone posted the minimum required code to have a new control that exposes the proper paint events for you by hosting a rich textbox and intercepting the windows paint requests. It is in VB.Net but should be easy to translate it for your use.

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. In case it would be useful for you here is online code converter http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/