# How can i drawstring on a richTextBox1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a new `UserControl` in the designer I added a richTextBox. Then I did in the `UserControl` constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    public partial class ScrollText : UserControl
    {
        Font drawFonts1 = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Point pt = new Point(50, 50);

        public ScrollText()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            System.Drawing.Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("hi",5);
            Graphics e = richTextBox1.CreateGraphics();
            e.DrawString("hello",drawFonts1,new SolidBrush(Color.Red),pt);
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I dragged the new `UserControl` into the `form1` designer but it's empty. I don't see the word "hello".

Comment: Do you have a font installed called "hi"? Oh wait, you are not using `f`.

Comment: As soon as you `Invalidate`, your `Form` repaints itself, including your `RickTextBox` control (I guess), in turn `RickTextBox` control redraws itself, and removing anything extra stuff drawn over it.

Comment: Removed the Invalidate didn't help. Tried to make richTextBox1.Invalidate in all cases it didn't draw the text. With or without the invalidate.

Comment: Do you know how control rendering is done? Try to look at `Paint` event

Comment: richTextBox dosent have paint event

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extend the `RichTextBox` control and implement your custom drawing in `OnPaint` method. But normally `RichTextBox` control does NOT call the `OnPaint` method so you have to call the method manually by [hooking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041348/richtextbox-and-userpaint) in `WndProc` method.

Example:

```
class ExtendedRTB : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
{
    // this piece of code was taken from pgfearo's answer
    // ------------------------------------------
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041348/richtextbox-and-userpaint
    private const int WM_PAINT = 15;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            // raise the paint event
            using (Graphics graphic = base.CreateGraphics())
                OnPaint(new PaintEventArgs(graphic,
                 base.ClientRectangle));
        }

    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------

    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("hello", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: sallushan i tried your solution strange: when i drag the control in form1 designer around on form1 designer i see the text hello but once i leave the control on place and not drag it i dont see the hello text just white back color on the control. And i used a breakpoitn and it's getting to the paint event but only when i drag the usercontrol i see the hello.

Comment: sallushan i found the problem. Your solution is drawing the string on the UserControl not on the richTextBox. My richTextBox is on the UserControl designer. Maybe im missing here something.

Comment: You can see in my updated question i edited it with a screenshot. The "hello" is drawed on the UserControl but not on the richTextBox1 in the UserControl designer !

Comment: Are you trying to see "Hello" on design mode? Even if you see on design mode what benefit it will give you? The solution is for run-time.